# Wikitude plugin in Xamarin captured image

Tags: c#, xamarin, wikitude

I have created a new plugin for Wikitude. I want to send the recognized image to another API . in the first place I have to get the image but I'm failed.
 I have asked this question in Wikitude forums too but no one answer.
Here is my plugin code:
I'm using Wikitude 6.0 and VisualStudio 2017

```
 public class Plugin02 : Com.Wikitude.Common.Plugins.Plugin
{
    public Plugin02(string p0) : base(p0)
    {
    }
    public override void CameraFrameAvailable(Frame p0)
    {
        try
        {
            // try 1
            BitmapFactory.Options Options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InSampleSize = 1 };
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(p0.GetData(), 0, p0.GetData().Length, Options);
            SaveBitmap(bitmap);
            // result : bitmap is always null


            //try 2
            var yuv = new YuvImage(p0.GetData(), ImageFormatType.Nv21, p0.Size.Width, p0.Size.Height, null);
            // var bmp = a.b(currentFrame.GetData(), currentFrame.GetData().Length, currentFrame.Size.Width, currentFrame.Size.Height);
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var quality = 100;   // adjust this as needed
            yuv.CompressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, yuv.Width, yuv.Height), quality, ms);
            var jpegData = ms.ToArray();
            Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(jpegData, 0, jpegData.Length);
            SaveBitmap(bitmap2);
            // result : image is not clear
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { }
    }
    void SaveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + ".jpg");
        var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
        stream.Close();
    }
    public override void Update(RecognizedTarget[] p0)
    {

    }
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }
    protected override void Pause()
    {
        base.Pause();
    }
    protected override void Resume(long p0)
    {
        base.Resume(p0);
    }
    protected override void Destroy()
    {
        base.Destroy();
    }

}
```

Here is my new code:

```
 public class Plugin01 : Com.Wikitude.Common.Plugins.Plugin
{
    TesseractApi api;
    public Plugin01(string p0) : base(p0)
    {
        api = new TesseractApi(Application.Context, AssetsDeployment.OncePerVersion);
        api.Init("eng");
    }


    Frame currentFrame = null;
    public override void CameraFrameAvailable(Frame p0)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = p0.GetData();
            currentFrame = p0;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { }
    }

    public override void Update(RecognizedTarget[] p0)
    {
        if (p0 != null)
        {
            if (currentFrame != null)
            {
                ConvertYuvToJpeg(currentFrame, p0[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }
    protected override void Pause()
    {
        base.Pause();
    }
    protected override void Resume(long p0)
    {
        base.Resume(p0);
    }
    protected override void Destroy()
    {
        base.Destroy();
    }

    private void ConvertYuvToJpeg(Frame frame, RecognizedTarget p00)
    {
        try
        {
            YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(frame.GetData(), ImageFormatType.Nv21, frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height, null);
            var outStream = new MemoryStream();
            var left = p00.TargetPositionInCameraFrame.Origin.GetY() + 10;
            var top = p00.TargetPositionInCameraFrame.Origin.GetX()+20;
            var right = left + p00.TargetPositionInCameraFrame.Size.Width;
            var bottom = top + p00.TargetPositionInCameraFrame.Size.Height;
            Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);

            yuvimage.CompressToJpeg(rect, 100, outStream);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(outStream.ToArray(), 0, outStream.ToArray().Length);

            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.PreRotate(90);
            bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, mtx, false);

            var outStream1 = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, outStream1);
            var bmpA = bmp.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);

            api.SetImage(outStream1);
            //api.Results(Tesseract.PageIteratorLevel.Block);
            if (api.Text != null)
            {
            }

            var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + ".jpg");
            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            bmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { }

    }

}
```

and Here is image sample:
[image]

according to what [wikitude support said](https://support.wikitude.com/support/discussions/topics/5000082846) the image format is YV12 for Android and I couldn't find any way to convert it RGB or like that the only one was the Nv21 format.

I've added the YUV to RGB converter as you said and here is new code but something is wrong.
The length of getData() is more than width * height.

```
public override void Update(RecognizedTarget[] p0)
    {
        if (p0 != null)
        {
            if (currentFrame != null)
            {
                //ConvertYuvToJpeg(currentFrame, p0[0]);
                ConvertYuvToRGB(currentFrame, p0[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    private void ConvertYuvToRGB(Frame frame, RecognizedTarget p00)
    {
        try
        {
            var rgbData = convertYUV420_NV21toARGB8888(frame.GetData(), frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height);
            var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
            // vector is your int[] of ARGB 
            bitmap.CopyPixelsFromBuffer(Java.Nio.IntBuffer.Wrap(rgbData));
            var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + ".jpg");
            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { }
    }
    public static int[] convertYUV420_NV21toARGB8888(byte[] data, int width, int height)
    {
        int size = width * height;
        int offset = size;
        int[] pixels = new int[size];
        int u, v, y1, y2, y3, y4;

        // i along Y and the final pixels
        // k along pixels U and V
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < size; i += 2, k += 2)
        {
            y1 = data[i] & 0xff;
            y2 = data[i + 1] & 0xff;
            y3 = data[width + i] & 0xff;
            y4 = data[width + i + 1] & 0xff;

            u = data[offset + k] & 0xff;
            v = data[offset + k + size / 4] & 0xff;
            v = v - 128;
            u = u - 128;

            pixels[i] = convertYUVtoARGB(y1, u, v);
            pixels[i + 1] = convertYUVtoARGB(y2, u, v);
            pixels[width + i] = convertYUVtoARGB(y3, u, v);
            pixels[width + i + 1] = convertYUVtoARGB(y4, u, v);

            if (i != 0 && (i + 2) % width == 0)
                i += width;
        }

        return pixels;
    }
    private static int convertYUVtoARGB(int y, int u, int v)
    {
        int r = y + (int)(1.772f * v);
        int g = y - (int)(0.344f * v + 0.714f * u);
        int b = y + (int)(1.402f * u);
        r = r > 255 ? 255 : r < 0 ? 0 : r;
        g = g > 255 ? 255 : g < 0 ? 0 : g;
        b = b > 255 ? 255 : b < 0 ? 0 : b;
        return (int)(4278190080 | ((r + 16) | ((g + 8) | b)));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "result : image is not clear" ?

Comment: If the colors are wrong the reason could be that you are using ImageFormat.Nv21 instead of Yv12

Comment: I added an image sample for you @Alex

Comment: It seems like the luminance is correct but the chrominance is wrong. 
Have you tried this YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(frame.GetData(), ImageFormatType.Yv12, frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height, null) in your ConvertYuvToJpeg() already?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.
Apparently "YuvImage " only support ImageFormat.NV21 and ImageFormat.YUY2.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060679/yuv420p-and-yv12-or-yv12-to-rgb888-conversion

Comment: Please note the answer to the stackoverflow question i linked - "and k in loop should increase by 1 (not by 2).". The length of getData will be width*height*1.5 which is the size of a YUV Frame in bytes.

Comment: Hi are you able to fix this issue ?

Comment: @pritam001 Hi, I used the code that Alex sent me in previous comment

Comment: @HamidFathi Thanks :) ...I will check it I have the same requirement...

Comment: Hi @HamidFathi  I have a question I am new to xamarin..how did you create this plugin..How did you communicate with it ....If you dont mind can share any sample code or something....Thank you

Comment: Hi @pritam001. Creating a plugin is easy. you just need to implement Com.Wikitude.Common.Plugins.Plugin interface like the plugin which I send up there. for communicating you treat it like the sample in Wikitude documentation just as Java code in this link: https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/androidnative/pluginsapi.html#plugins-api
if you couldn't do that send your code in new question and we will find the answer.

Comment: Hi @HamidFathi I have posted the question with my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707586/how-to-use-wikitude-plugin-in-xamarin-forms Please have a look...I appreciate help on this