# How to use wikitude plugin in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, wikitude

I am using Xamarin to develop cross platform AR application. I am using Wikitude instant tracking.

I am able to start the Wikitude activity and able to run the Instant tracking...Now I  want capture the high resolution image while tracking...I am trying to build the plugin to get the frame and then convert it to image stream

Her is my Wikitude activity

```
 namespace XamarinExample.Droid
    {
        [Activity(Label = "WikitudeActivity")]
        public class WikitudeActivity : Activity, ArchitectView.IArchitectUrlListener
        {
            ArchitectView architectView;
            string worldUrl;

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.sample_cam);

                Title = Intent.GetStringExtra("id");

                worldUrl = "Wikitude" + File.Separator + Intent.GetStringExtra("id") + File.Separator + "index.html";

                architectView = FindViewById<ArchitectView>(Resource.Id.architectView);

                ArchitectStartupConfiguration startupConfiguration = new ArchitectStartupConfiguration();
                startupConfiguration.setLicenseKey(Constants.WIKITUDE_SDK_KEY);
                startupConfiguration.setFeatures(ArchitectStartupConfiguration.Features.ImageTracking);
                startupConfiguration.setCameraResolution(CameraSettings.CameraResolution.Auto);



/////////////////////////////// Register  Plugin////////////////////////////////////


                var plugins = new Plugin01("test");
                architectView.RegisterPlugin(plugins);

                architectView.OnCreate(startupConfiguration);
                architectView.RegisterUrlListener(this);
            }

    }
```

[My Plugin code taken from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843912/wikitude-plugin-in-xamarin-captured-image?noredirect=1#comment80270100_43843912)

```
public class Plugin01 : Com.Wikitude.Common.Plugins.Plugin
 {
    public Plugin01(string p0) : base(p0)
    {

    }    
    Frame currentFrame = null;
    public override void CameraFrameAvailable(Frame p0)
    {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AVAILABLE FRAME");
        try
        {
            var data = p0.GetData();
            currentFrame = p0;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { }
    }

    public override void Update(RecognizedTarget[] p0)
    {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AVAILABLE FRAME");
        if (p0 != null)
        {
            if (currentFrame != null)
            {
               // ConvertYuvToJpeg(currentFrame, p0[0]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have registered the plugins but it is not calling
public override void Update(RecognizedTarget[] p0) Method....What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please narrow the code down to where exactly you have your problem. Just dumping all your code and expecting someone to give you an answer won't work.

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron I have narrow down the code...My problem is I am not getting callback on ameraFrameAvailable(Frame p0) ..I have registered the plugin in first code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is calling "RegisterPlugin" in the wrong method, as you know the cycle of calling activity methods are different.you should call it in "OnPostCreate" method of activity.
try below code and let me know the result:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        try
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            architectView = FindViewById<ArchitectView>(Resource.Id.architectView);
            var config = new ArchitectStartupConfiguration();
            config.setLicenseKey(WIKITUDE_SDK_KEY);
            architectView.OnCreate(config);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Long); }
    }

protected override void OnPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (architectView != null)
            architectView.OnPostCreate();
        try
        {
            try
            {
                string url = string.Format(@"file:///android_asset/01_ImageRecognition_1_ImageOnTarget/index.html");
                architectView.Load(url);
                Plugin01 cardPlugin = new Plugin01("com.plugin.dpiar");
                architectView.RegisterPlugin(cardPlugin);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Long); }
    }
```

consider changing variables name.

Comment: Hi @hamid it is working :) thank you....I have one question now probably you solved it  ...I am trying to capture the image it working....But I have a same issue that you had....Please ifnd the attachment for the same

Comment: Here is my code https://gist.github.com/pritasam/d3f3614ea9cba4e8e8f4725c248a4d00